# f5 and t keydown/keypress keycodes

Tags: firefox

When I get the key code for a key pressed, I output the key codes into the console. I record two key codes: keydown and keypress.

When I press **F5**, I get the following key codes:

```
keydown = 84 ("T")
keypress = 116 ("t")
```

When I press **t**, I get the following key codes:

```
keydown = 116 ("t")
keypress = 116 ("t")
```

This only occurs in Firefox. Why are the keypress keycodes the same, and the keydown codes similar, when the original key that was pressed is not the same?

Comment: I wrote a library to translate keydown and keypress events to characters and keys, which would make this much easier - no dealing with keycodes and charcodes: https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not confusing `keyCode` and `charCode`?

Using the result from the bottom of [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html), I get

- **F5**

  - keydown: keyCode is 116; charCode is 0
  - keypress: keyCode is 116; charCode is 0
- **t**

  - keydown: keyCode is 84; charCode is 0
  - keypress: keyCode is 0; charCode is 116
- **T**

  - keydown: keyCode is 84; charCode is 0
  - keypress: keyCode is 0; charCode is 84

`keyCode` represents the actual keyboard key pressed by the user, whereas `charCode` represents the code point of the character. For example, the keys **t** and **T** have the same `keyCode` since they result from the same key, while they have different `charCode` because they stand for different characters.

So to answer your question, the output that you get for **F5** keydown is 84, which when plugged into `String.fromCharCode()` gives "T", while for keypress is 116, which corresponds to "t" using `String.fromCharCode()`.

In short, don't use `String.fromCharCode()` on `keyCode`, as the result is nonsensical. Only use it on `charCode`. Also from [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html), under "Special keys"

> If you need to detect these keys, do yourself a favour and search for their keyCode onkeydown/up, and ignore both onkeypress and charCode.